How to install .NET 4.5.2 using Scoop or at all on Windows 11?
I want to install carnac via scoop:
scoop install carnac
Installing 'carnac' (2.3.13) [64bit] from 'extras' bucket
carnac-2.3.13-full.nupkg (3.0 MB) [===========================================================================] 100%
Checking hash of carnac-2.3.13-full.nupkg ... ok.
Extracting carnac-2.3.13-full.nupkg ... done.
Linking ~\scoop\apps\carnac\current => ~\scoop\apps\carnac\2.3.13
Creating shortcut for Carnac (Carnac.exe)
Persisting Keymaps
'carnac' (2.3.13) was installed successfully!
Notes
-----
.NET Framework 4.5.2 is required.

It says .NET Framework 4.5.2 is required. Can I install that via scoop as well? If so, how?

I even tried manually installing .net 4.5.2, yet scoop install still complains that .net 4.5.2 is required. What am I missing?
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net452-developer-pack-offline-installer

Note: The 4.5.2 release is end of life.

If it works despite the message, then the message should have said "at least 4.5.2." If it doesn't work, you could copy the project from GitHub and compile it for .NET Framework 4.8.1.

NET Framework 4.5.2 cannot be installed on a system that already has NET Framework 4.8.1 installed.  NET Framework 4.8.1 is installed on ALL versions of Windows 11.

I would echo the first message.  The package was successfully installed.  The message is a note, not a warning or an error, so there shouldn't be any reason the package cannot be used.

carnac should work on Windows 11 out of the box with a more recent .NET 4.x version, the compatibility is listed on its homepage and it also seems to be working for me after a quick look.
The .NET Framework 4.5.2 framework is required line is just a random note included in the scoop recipe - it can be safely ignored:
"notes": ".NET Framework 4.5.2 is required.",

